# Pygame compiled cursor string not giving enough data

Tags: pygame, mouse

I'm trying to compile a cursor string provided by pygame and set the cursor to it. However, only 2 of the necessary 4 arguments are returned from the string compiler.

```
pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.broken_x)
cursor = pygame.cursors.compile(pygame.cursors.sizer_x_strings)
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in __init__
    pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*cursor)
TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The premade strings in pygame.cursors.* don't contain any metadata about the cursor, only the raw string. To effectively use them, you have to also provide the size (width in characters and height in lines) of the cursor string.
Here's an example that uses that premade cursor:

```
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

cursor, mask = pygame.cursors.compile(pygame.cursors.sizer_x_strings, "X", ".")

cursor_sizer = ((24, 16), (7, 11), cursor, mask)
pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*cursor_sizer)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((120, 120, 120))
    pygame.display.update()
```